# Lotus Notes LDAP Export

Tags: sql, ldap, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Im trying to export a Lotus Notes LDIF to MYSQL. I'v been able to perform a LDAPSEARCH and obtain all the users on a test server. Like fake user for example:

```
# Esteban Roberto Banquito, tsj, AR
dn: CN=Esteban Roberto Banquito,O=tsj,C=AR
cn: Esteban Roberto Banquito
cn: Esteban Banquito
displayname: Esteban Roberto Banquito/tsj/AR
inetpublickey:: MzA4MTlGMzAgMEQwNjA5MkEgODY0ODg2RjcgMEQwMTAxMDEAMDUwMDAzODEgOE
 QwMDMwODEgODkwMjgxODEgMDBDMTFDQjQAQjQ4Njg1NDggQjhDNTE5NEQgN0Y5QkE3MTEgNTYzRDF
 GRjAAQTQ0RjNERjEgMkIxQjQzM0UgQkVFQjA3M0EgRjk1RjdFMTYAQ0Q1QkFDQ0MgQjg3RUE0NjYg
 QjUzMjRENzYgQ0M3QzJEMjAAQ0Y1MjIxMDYgMzU4NkRENzAgMDE1ODE5MjAgOUU0NTFCODcANDc1M
 DFBMzkgRDY4RjREQTQgNUUyMkUwQzcgOTk5NUQ4MzcAMjUwRUJDQjYgMkY5MkM0NTEgOUU1QTZCRE
 YgNEMwNzIwNjEANENDMTRDODUgQUIyOTE4OTIgNDAxRUFDMEQgOTlCOTBFQjUANkMwNTMzODEgMkN
 DNjJCQkEgRTVBMzYyMUQgOEIwMjAzMDEAMDAwMQ==
objectclass: dominoPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: top
mailsystem: 1
messagestorage: 1
encryptincomingmail: 0
dominocertificate:: MDQwMEM2MDEgNkJFNDFCMjggMEFHMDE2MjYgRzAwMjkxNTEANDNGM0YzMD
 MgRzAwMzAyMDAgMDEyMEEyMDAgRjFDQTQ4MDAARDU3RTI1RzAgMDI4MEcwMDIgMEZDQjQ4MDAgRDQ
 3RTI1MDAAM0M4NTQ4MDAgQjA4MTI1ODMgMDFBMEcwMDEgRjFDQTQ4MDAARDU3RTI1RzAgMDYwRkNC
 NDggMDBENDdFMjUgMDAzQzg1NDgAMDBCMDgxMjUgODM0RjNENzQgNzM2QTJGNDMgM0Q0MTUyNDMAN
 EUzRDQ1NzMgNzQ2NTYyNjEgNkUyMDUyNkYgNjI2NTcyNzQANkYyMDQyNjEgNkU3MTc1NjkgNzQ2Rj
 JGNEYgM0Q3NDczNkEAMkY0MzNENDEgNTIzMDgxOUYgMzAwRDA2MDkgMkE4NjQ4ODYARjcwRDAxMDE
 gMDEwNTAwMDMgODE4RDAwMzAgODE4OTAyODEAODEwMEMwOEMgMEUzQTEwNTAgQkZBODczQTAgODJE
 NENDRjgAQzk3QzQwNDAgRTI0NjdDMTYgODU1QTEwMjQgQUI1RjEyNDQAOUE0OTYyMkEgODZGODhDM
 DggNkVCOTg4REYgN0Y2NkZCMjEAQkY2MkM1RjYgRThBRUE0NzQgNUU4RUZDN0QgNDQ4QjRDN0YANz
 A3MENCRTMgODcxRDhCMDMgOENDOTIwNDQgRkYwNzA4MDUANTg2MEQ0NkYgQzk2QjczNkYgRjMzRDR
 FRUQgN0M5MDIyMkYAOUU0OTZDNUMgMUJEMzQxODcgOUM2N0FEREYgOTFFNDIyNTQANkU1QkY4MkMg
 QjNGMEUyRjEgNEI0MTkxMjEgRTBCMEQzN0UAQ0FGRjAyMDMgMDEwMDAxMTQgQjhEQjc3MzUgRkNFM
 0Q0MzkAMjc0RDg0OEEgREM0MkQ0N0YgREFBN0M5RkMgMEQwRDgyOTMANUVENjkyNzYgQkUwRjY0RU
 QgRDFBQkQzRDYgRjA5MkZDNjAANjgzMUM1RTcgNkQ2OEVDRDkgNDI2RTlDQzkgMkM2MjNCNEYAQzR
 DRTUxQzIgMTNFQkQyMUUgNjFFRkE3RTAgQ0Q1RjIxNjEAQzhFMjU1RDkgNjY1RURFRDEgMzJEMUY4
 MzEgQjc0RTk2QkQANTYzMDFCQkEgNTgzRDA3NTQgNjA2MDEzMzMgMjZBRTk0RTUAQjI2OURENDUgN
 jRDMEQ5Q0YgQTBCRDFGNjMgODc5OTA4OUEAMkRFQjVFMkEgNUY1OUYz
roamcleansetting: 0
roamcleanper: 1
availablefordirsync: 1
checkpassword: 0
passwordchangeinterval: 0
passwordgraceperiod: 0
clienttype: 0
givenname: Esteban
middleinitial: Roberto
sn: Banquito
uid: EBanquito
maildomain: tsj
mailserver: CN=tsjdesarrollo,OU=tsjdesarrollo,O=tsj,C=AR
mailfile: mail\ebanquit
roaminguser: 0
httppasswordchangedate: 20151022045930Z
userpassword:: KEdLUy9sSWdZQjdsUWxudzh1MzYvKQ==
```

The issue is the `USERPASSWORD` it seems that is base64, after decode i obtain something like this: `(GKS/lIgYB7lQlnw8u36/)` , the real password is "secreto".

Is there any way to use the `dominocertificate` and the `inetpublickey` or other certificate to decode the field ?

Comment: It is actually not an "issue", but security by design. It would be otherwise to easy to break in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to decode the HTTP password.

Here's a detailed explanation: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/e5f5333619f2996885256a220009508f/d64ea26425fb0be88525709200800958?OpenDocument